# zsh yanks only last cut word

Tags: zsh, cut

I've been using `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh` for nearly three years, mostly on debian systems.
I'm using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> a lot. For three weeks now my workstation is a MacBook and I've been using `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` on it too. But there's a awkward behavior.

When I cut multiple words backwards using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and try to yank the cut words with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>, only the last cut word is pasted. As far as I know it, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> yanks all the last cut words.

Can anybody tell me, which parameter is responsible for that?

**Edit:** '^W' is bound to backward-kill-word. Shouldn't it be backward-delete-word?

**Edit 2:** Ok, I've found out that zsh-autosuggestions is responsible for this. After disabling this ctrl^w and ctrl^y are working like expected. I think, I have to dig into zsh-autosuggestions configuration to get to the parameter changing the behaviour.

**Edit 3:** When zsh-autosuggestions is enabled `zle -lLa backward-kill-word` returns this

```
zle -N backward-kill-word _zsh_autosuggest_bound_1_backward-kill-word
```

and `which _zsh_autosuggest_bound_1_backward-kill-word` returns

```
_zsh_autosuggest_bound_1_backward-kill-word () {
_zsh_autosuggest_widget_modify autosuggest-orig-1-backward-kill-word $@}
```

I'm not very into deep in the zsh, so I don't know exactly what this means. But my guess is, that zsh-autosuggestions kind of "overrides" the default functionality of backward-kill-word, right?

Comment: Most probably, you or one of the oh-my-zsh modules you've enabled remaps the word cutting widgets to some that don't preserve that property. What is `^W` bound to? What's the output of `bindkey '^W'`? And `zle -lLa thewidget` for the widget mentioned in the output of bindkey, and `which thefunction` for the function that widget uses if any.

Comment: backward-delete-word is the default widget (see `zsh -f` for the default behaviour). But the question is, has the widget been redefined. Does `zle -lLa backward-kill-word` return something? If yes, can you run `which` on the last word in the line it reports. Please add the information to your question by clicking on the [edit] link

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found out that zsh-autosuggestions is responsible for this. After disabling this ctrl^w and ctrl^y are working like expected. I think, I have to dig into zsh-autosuggestions configuration to get to the parameter changing the behaviour.

Comment: More likely that extension doesn't support preserving that. You could raise a bug report about it. See the manual about `zle -f kill` in recent versions of zsh and see how other extensions like `backward-kill-word-match` do it.

Comment: The appropriate issue appears to be [Autosuggest eats buffer by ctrl+w (#363)](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/363).

Comment: [Disabled](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/363#issuecomment-449554814) by adding `ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_IGNORE_WIDGETS+=(backward-kill-word)` to `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
bindkey "^W" kill-region
```

to your `.zshrc` file, then run `source .zshrc`, and I think you will get the emacs behavior.